# PrimeFaces rowsperpagetemplate

Tags: javascript, primefaces

```
<p:dataTable
            styleClass="wr_datatable"
            id="study_tab"
            paginatorPosition="bottom"
            var="datas"
            value="#{datasBean.listDatas}"
            widgetVar="dataTable"
            emptyMessage="No data found. Please change the search criteria above."
            paginator="true"
            selection="#{dataBean.selectedData}"
            rowKey="#{datas.data_pk}"
            selectionMode="single"
            rowIndexVar="indexvar"
            draggableColumns="true"
            resizableColumns="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}
            {FirstPageLink}
            {PreviousPageLink}
            {PageLinks}
            {NextPageLink}
            {LastPageLink}
            {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rows="10"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20"
```

I setup my tabular data structure view like above.

I can get the current page using the below code:

```
(PF('dataTable').paginator.getCurrentPage()
```

I was just wondering how I can get the primefaces rowpagetemplate or row dynamically in my Javascript?({RowsPerPageDropdown} to be precise.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current number of rows using `PF('widgetVar').getPaginator().getRows()` which should match the current rowsPerPage value.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. It looks like a hack. 
Would like to know if anyone would have approached it differently?

```
function getSelectedPaginationValue() {
 return $('#primefacesSelectID').val();
  }

    function selectme(x) {

   if (PF('dataTable').paginator.getCurrentPage() >0){
    var row_number = x - getSelectedPaginationValue() * PF('dataTable').paginator.getCurrentPage();
   PF('dataTable').unselectAllRows();
   PF('dataTable').selectRow((row_number));

   } else {
    var row_number = x;
    PF('dataTable').unselectAllRows();
    PF('dataTable').selectRow((row_number));
  }
  }
```